# Power Platform Plugin Development using TypeScript/Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, power-platform

1. Is it possible to use TypeScript/Nodejs instead of C# to create a Power Platform Plugin?
2. Is there any example code or instructions on how to do this?